# CakePHP 3:Router error, htaccess auto redirect webroot/admin/

Tags: php, .htaccess, admin, cakephp-3.0

When I enter `localhost:3000/admin`
the url redirects to `localhost:3000/webroot/admin`
and show error WebrootController not found

But I enter `localhost:3000/admin/` is correct
router

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    //$routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['prefix' => 'admin']);
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

My project

[image]

Comment: And what, exactly, is your question? Please click the EDIT link in the question and add that information.

Comment: thanks you. I sorry because I write english is bad

Comment: have you defined `webroot` as the actual document root in Apache? I am a little confused to what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or change folder name admin in webroot

its may be a cakephp bug.